# Watching state object in pinia doesn't fire when object changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, pinia

I have a deep object in my pinia state that I want to put a watcher on.

```js
export const useProductStore = defineStore("product", {
  state: () => ({
    attributes: {},
  }),
});
```

When the object has data inside it can look like this:

```json
attributes: {
  english: {
    0: {
      key: "key1",
      value: "value1"
    },
    1: {
      key: "key2",
      value: "value2"
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

I'm trying to put a watcher on this object but when the value changes the watch doesn't fire.  Here's the component I'm trying to do this in:

```js
<script setup>
  import { useProductStore } from "@/stores/ProductStore";
  import { storeToRefs } from "pinia";

  const productStore = useProductStore();
  const { attributes } = storeToRefs(productStore);

  watch(() => ({...attributes}), (newValue, oldValue) => {
    console.log(oldValue);
    console.log(newValue);
  }, { deep: true });
</script>
```

This comes straight from the pinia documentation, but when I change the state, nothing happens.  Using vue dev tools I can see the state object being changed, so I know it is reactive.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`storeToRefs` produces [`ref()`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref)s.

You're saying the example *"comes straight from the pinia documentation"*, but I doubt you found spreading a `ref` anywhere in pinia docs. If you did, it's a mistake and should be pointed out to posva, by opening an issue on `pinia`'s repo.

A ref can be watched directly:

```js
watch(
  attributes,
  handler, 
  { deep: true }
)
```

...or you could watch its `.value` with an arrow function ***<sup>1</sup>***:

```js
watch(
  () => attributes.value,
  handler,
  { deep: true }
)
```

Note `newVal` and `oldVal` arguments are [Proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) ***<sup>2</sup>***. To access their targets, use [toRaw](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-advanced.html#toraw).

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/practical-scooby-5hbk7f?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue).

---

***<sup>1</sup>*** - it allows for narrower watchers, such as:

```js
watch(
  () => attributes.value[0]?.value),
  handler
)
```

***<sup>2</sup>*** - if you place an object in a `ref()` *"the object is made deeply reactive with `reactive()`"* (see [details](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref)). Also read [Reactive Proxy vs Original](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#reactive-proxy-vs-original-1).